# Many times cypress can't visit /auth page and can't find id or class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I am trying to visit `/auth` path and login in with cypress using the following code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
  cy.get('.auth').find('.login').should(($login) => {
    expect($login).to.contain('auth.welcome')
  })

  cy.get('[name="email"]').type(email);
  cy.get('[name="password"]').type(password);

  cy.get('button.login')
    .click();
})
```

But Cypress fails with the following error message:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: `.auth`, but never found it.
```

Sometimes the code works and sometimes it fails.

*my login page url is (http://localhost:3000/) or (http://localhost:3000/auth)*

Comment: Maybe it is already authenticated and when visiting login page there's a redirect to some other page?

Comment: @AlekseyL. it's for first time going to authentication but timed out in cy.visit(/)

Comment: Could you share what is under the hood of your `login` command?

Comment: @AlexIzbas login code updated

Comment: The problem here is that `get` is not retried because it is followed by `find`. Try to change the command to `cy.get('.auth .login').should($login => ...)`

Answer (score 3):

this command will wait the element:

```
cy.get('.auth').should('be.visible');
```

Add this command before interacting with it.

Answer (score 3):

***Custom commands*** are very good utilities, but encapsulating multiple UI actions inside, make the overall test execution very slow and flaky especially for `login` actions.

It is not wrong at all your approach, however I would suggest doing it via API calls, so in result you will have a stable and robust login function.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
    return cy
        .request('POST', `${<YOUR_API_URL>}/auth`, {
            username,
            password,
        })
        .its('body.token')
        .then(token => {
            cy.visit(`/`, {
                onBeforeLoad(win) {
                    win.sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
                },
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Wrapping multiple UI actions inside command is no different in running those commands in test itself and if it flaky - that's not because of custom command but because of some other problem