# How to preserve login in cypress e2e tests?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have implemented some cypress e2e tests.
But, before each, `it()` block it performs login step.
I want to make login once for every test suit.(for decreasing tests run time)

my tests structure is as below :

```
describe('Main Suit', () => {
  
    before(() => {
      cy.visit('/register')

      // Steps to register
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('/login')
      cy.get('#email').type('test12@gmail.com');
      cy.get('#password').type('password')
      cy.get('.p-button').click()
      cy.wait(2000)
    })

    describe('test suit - 1', () => {
      
      it('test - 1', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })

      it('test - 2', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })
          
      it('test - 3', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })

    });


    describe('test suit - 2', () => {
      
      it('test - 1', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })

      it('test - 2', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })
          
      it('test - 3', () => {
        cy.visit('/somePath')
        cy.get('table').contains('td', 'No data found.');
        cy.wait(2000)
      })

    });

});
```

I have tried cy.session().
But, It did not worked.

my cypress version is **^10.4.0**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. May I ask: why you don't manage the login through the api and simply store the session in the browser? This is much cheaper in terms of performance.

Comment: Hi, @AlexIzbas
Thanks for the suggestion.
Would you please share some reference links?
So, I can implement it.

Comment: Here is a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028461/10494949.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for help.

After digging deep.
I have found the solution.

I have added below statement under **cypress.config.js** file under e2e block :

```
experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
```

And added below block of code before all test suits :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session('user', () => {
      cy.visit('/login');
      cy.get('#email').type('test12@gmail.com');
      cy.get('#password').type('password');
      cy.get('.p-button').click();
      cy.wait(2000);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi @jigneshpatel !
I high recommended use command and in your type('password') the {log:false} as second argument [How to protect sensitive data with Cypress](https://dev.to/walmyrlimaesilv/how-to-protect-sensitive-data-with-cypress-44d3)

Answer (score 1):

The `cy.session()` command is designed to do exactly what you want.

If it did not work, perhaps you are using it incorrectly?

A common mistake is to call it just once. Instead it must be in `beforeEach()`, but it does not perform the login for each test - the first test it will run `setup()`, for each other test it will just restore the login credentials (either cookies, localstorage, or session storage).

```js
beforeEach(() => {

  const setup = () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('#email').type('test12@gmail.com');
    cy.get('#password').type('password')
    cy.get('.p-button').click()
  })
  
  cy.session('login', setup())
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Fody
I have added your beforeEach() block.
But, I am getting new error "cy.session() requires enabling the experimentalSessionAndOrigin flag."

and If I enable "experimentalSessionAndOrigin" I get another error : 
cy.session() requires enabling the experimentalSessionAndOrigin flag. The experimentalSessionSupport flag was enabled but was removed in Cypress version 9.6.0.

Comment: Yes the flag is `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true` and it should be in the `e2e: { }` section of the config. Here's the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments#End-to-End-Testing)

Comment: Now I am getting this error :
No session is defined with the name
login
In order to use cy.session(), provide a setup as the second argument: